# Posting photo to page albums causing error message #3 Application does not have the capability to make this API call

Tags: facebook, api

Posting photo to page albums causing error message #3 Application does not have the capability to make this API call. Posting to another album on same page works fine. page access token same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and so created a Facebook [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/319253291461871) for it. It came back with a response from Facebook that this happens if user who has the problem has given restricted permissions to the app used to post in behalf of the user. In my case the user had granted my app a level "me only" but then wanted to make a post to a public album using this app.

So the solution would be to catch his error and display an error message to end user: "You have not granted enough privileges to the app to post on your behalf. Please go to Facebook->Account Settings->Apps and change 'Who can see posts this app makes for me on Facebook?' to 'Public'"